# How to acces Web Sevice by SSL CERTIFICATE

Tags: php, rest, web-services, https, ssl-certificate

how i can establish connection in this situation :

I want to consume Web Service that required ssl certificat connection,

in first step the web sevice owner ask me for CSR (CERTIFICATE REQUEST),
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

then i generate CSR file, and send it to the owner,
then he send me back sign CERTIFICATE file with **.cer** extension,
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

i want to know how i can use this file to establish connection.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use _client side certificates_ ? Not really a typical things to do ... Anyway you could do that, the client would need to install (or use) that signed certificate for subsequent connections. But this does not really make any sense, because that would mean _anyone_ could request you to sign his certificate without you being able to authorize the request. Which means that the step would be completely arbitrary, you could as well just leave it away without any loss.

Comment: I got the impression that this is a classical XY problem we face. Which means that you ask how you might be able to do something that you _think_ might solve your issue. Don't. Instead simply ask how you can solve your actual issue.